# SSH to AWS EC2 instance hangs

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, amazon-ec2

I was able to log in to my ec2 instance via ssh few days ago. But somehow today when I connected it with
`ssh -i something.pem ubuntu@ip_address -v`
then the terminal hung on this line:
`debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6`. 
I've tried to reboot the ec2 instance but it's not working. 
security group is properly set up that allows ssh connection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is too general to debug based on your descriptions.

A few things you can try:

1. Instead of "rebooting" it: If your EC2 instance has EBS backed storage, you can try stopping it and starting it. This is different from rebooting.
2. Since you are using its IP address, check if instance's IP address has changed in AWS EC2 Console.
3. Check if security group settings have changed.
4. Let it hang long enough and see what SSH error message says. You may also use `ssh -vv` to get even more verbose outputs.
5. If it does not help, maybe post your `describe-instances` response here can help people make better estimates of your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Honestly I don't know what happened, just came back from the nap and re-ran the connection command, now it succeeds.

Comment: @zxcisnoias If that is the case, it sounds like some transient routing issue. Glad to know you do not have an issue anymore.